# Why does my fedora-admin.sh findObjects throw an exception?

Tags: tomcat7, fedora-commons

I recently upgraded from fedora-commons 3.7 to 3.8.1. I can search and ingest objects from the fedora-admin web panel, but when I run the /fedora/client/bin/fedora-admin.sh and try to search '*', I get this error:

```
WARN 09:33:21.111 (PhaseInterceptorChain) Interceptor for {http://fedora-commons.org/2011/07/definitions/types/}FedoraAPIAMTOMService#{http://fedora-commons.org/2011/07/definitions/types/}findObjects has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135) [cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.findObjects(Unknown Source) [na:na]
at org.fcrepo.client.mtom.APIAStubWrapper$7.construct(APIAStubWrapper.java:193) [fcrepo-client-admin-3.8.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.fcrepo.client.mtom.APIAStubWrapper$7.construct(APIAStubWrapper.java:187) [fcrepo-client-admin-3.8.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at org.fcrepo.client.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131) [fcrepo-client-admin-3.8.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://localhost:8080/fedora/services/accessMTOM
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1542) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-bundle-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
... 12 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "Thread-1" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:146)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.findObjects(Unknown Source)
at org.fcrepo.client.mtom.APIAStubWrapper$7.construct(APIAStubWrapper.java:193)
at org.fcrepo.client.mtom.APIAStubWrapper$7.construct(APIAStubWrapper.java:187)
at org.fcrepo.client.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://localhost:8080/fedora/services/accessMTOM
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1542)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
... 5 more
```

I am running the fedora-admin.sh as my fedora user. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an HTTP response code 401 unauthorized.

So I think you have enabled authentification on API-A when you installed Fedora Commons.

I had a similar problem with my installation and I solved it by setting up ssl by generating a .keystore with keytool and adding it to $JAVA_OPTS. I added this line in my .bashrc :

export JAVA_OPTS='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=~/.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=MyKeystorePassword'

then use command : source ~/.bashrc

You can verify if you have an issue from your ssl configuration by enabling access to Fedora API without HTTPS either by running again the install script either by editing your server configuration in $FEDORA_HOME/server/config If you no longer have that error, then check your java ssl configuration as above.